# Path, relative, direct

Tags: java, path

I know there were several similar questions, however, examples in them don't make things clear or I can't make profit of them - Shame on me.

So my problem is with loading images in simple app with GUI.
e.g.:

I got images in `"D:\javaeclipseprog\Graphics\src\images"`, class and java files in `"D:\javaeclipseprog\Graphics\src\app"`
When I use direct path: `"D:/javaeclipseprog/Graphics/src/images/icon.jpg"` everything works, but as good practice I would like to get them from relative path, which as far as I know should be: `"./images/icon.jpg"`.
Unfortunately it doesn't work.

Any help appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Should the path be relative to your working directory or to your class files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are running it in eclipse, your default working directory in the project directory. That is the directory where `src`is located in. In your example the project directory is:

```
D:/javaeclipseprog/Graphics
```

Therefore the correct path is:

```
./src/images/trophy.png
```

Edit: Just want to add that you could also load a file via a path relative to the class location by using the `getResource` method.

Comment: Beer :) ?
That is what I needed, so now it is clear that default working directory is in the project directory. Yeah I know i rewrite it :) It works also but understanding was more significant to me. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

`../../images/icon.jpg` should work fine

You're going two folders up and go straight to the right folder.

---

### Paths

A simple way to check this would be to use the `Paths` and `Path` classes and methods.

```
Path p1 = Paths.get("D:\\javaeclipseprog\\Graphics\\src\\app\\java.class");
Path p2 = Paths.get("..\\..\\images\\icon.jpg");

System.out.println(p1.resolve(p2).normalize()); // D:\javaeclipseprog\Graphics\src\images\icon.jpg
```

Comment: As API misses examples for this methods here are ones, easier to understand what was done above:
http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/java.nio.file/Path/Java_Tutorial_Path.htm

Answer (score 1):

I'll use the inverted slash because it seems that you use windows. In this case `.\` indicates that the same directory where the code is, will have the file you want to use. If you want to jump into the father of that directory, the one that contains the source, you'll use `..\`

You can even do it more tan once, for example `..\..\` would be a valid path. Try adding quantities of `..\` in order to look for the directory you want. In this chase `..\src\images\icon.jpg` (the parent on a java project is src)

Another important thing is that you're using `/` instead of `\\` that would be the symbol of the directory separator on windows (`\` is an special char that must be scaped using an aditional `\`) For portability i'd use:

```
  String sep = System.getProperty("file.separator");
  String path = ".."+sep+"src"+sep+"images"+sep+"icon.jpg"
```

Comment: nice point, it's true separator may differ according to platform where project would be run.

Comment: @kolboc: Actually the '/' works on all platforms that are currently relevant, even on Windows. But if you really want to be sure, it's ok to use the `file.separator` property.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to use is "../images/icon.jpg".

Using it like you have it will look in the current directory, which unless I'm understanding it incorrectly, is "D:\javaeclipseprog\Graphics\src\app".

Comment: The current directory has nothing to do with the location of the class files.

Comment: unfortunately still doesn't work :/
even tried .../src/images/trophy.png but it still doesn't work (with many dots options, which I think go "back" in directories)

Comment: @FrankPuffer could tell me more? :) I was feeling that's the deal but I couldn't make up what's really going on, api doesn't clarify it at all.

Comment: @kolboc: Did you check my answer?